# How to disable Remote Management and Screen Sharing Ports in OS X El Capitan Application Firewall?

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, firewall, osx-el-capitan

I have purchased an OS X 10.11 VPS. I would like to lock down the box to only allow port 22 SSH through the firewall. So I turned on the application firewall under System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Firewall. Problem I am having is I cannot disable "Remote Mangement" and "Screen Sharing" in the Firewall Options window. The UI will not allow me to select them. What am I missing? Thanks.

To be clear I don't want to turn off the VNC server. I want it to still work from localhost so I can tunnel to the VNC server.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first disable the Sharing settings under *System Preferences -> Sharing* and turn them off on the left by unchecking them which will automatically remove them from the Firewall allowed list.

Comment: Gotcha is I don't want to turn off the in-built VNC server. I want it to still work from localhost. Basically ssh into the box then setup a tunnel to the VNC server.